# What guarantees the existence of maximal atlas of a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension greater than 1, if $\mathfrak{U}$ is an atlas of $M$, then there exists a unique maximal atlas $\mathfrak{W}$ that contains $\mathfrak{U}$. What I am unsure is the existence of $\mathfrak{W}$. Of course if I assume the existence of such $\mathfrak{W}$, then uniqueness is clear. My question is, what guarantees the existence?

Clearly, a maximal atlas of $M$ must be uncountable, so I cannot inductively append chart by chart on $\mathfrak{U}$ to get $\mathfrak{W}$. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare that a pair $(U, \phi)$ where $U$ is an open in $M$ and $\phi: U \to V$ is an identification of $U$ with some open $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is in $\mathfrak{M}$ if and only if it is compatible with every such pair in $\mathfrak{U}$.

Here, compatibility means that if $(U', \phi')$ is some such pair in the atlas $\mathfrak{U}$ that you started with and $U'$ meets $U$, then $\phi'^{-1} \circ \phi$ is smooth (where the composition makes sense).

If this is an atlas, it's clearly maximal (anything compatible with all the charts in it is in particular compatible with all the charts in $\mathfrak{U}$, so in the $\mathfrak{M}$), but we have to check that any two charts we just added are compatible with each other.

This is true (omitting some details here) because the opens in $\mathfrak{U}$ cover $M$, so you can always compare (suitable refinements of) two charts in $\mathfrak{M}$ with a common chart in $\mathfrak{U}$, and compositions of smooth maps are smooth.

Comment: "If this is an atlas, it's clearly maximal." By this atlas, do you mean $\mathfrak{U}$? If so, I still do not understand why $\mathfrak{U}$ is maximal. If there exists some chart $(V,\psi)$ that is compatible with all charts in $\mathfrak{U}$, then $\mathfrak{U} \cup \{(V, \psi)\}$ is a 'larger' atlas than $\mathfrak{U}$ (meaning $\mathfrak{U}$ is not maximal).

Comment: For example, if $M = \mathbb{R^1}$ with standard topology, then I may construct an atlas covering $M$: $\mathfrak{U} = \{((x, x+r), id_{\mathbb{R}}) \mid x, r \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Clearly, $\mathfrak{U}$ is not maximal since it does not contain chart $((\pi, \pi+1), id)$. One atlas containing $\mathfrak{U}$ would be $\mathfrak{V} = \{(U, id_{\mathbb{R}^1}) \mid U \text{ is open in } \mathbb{R^1}\}$, but $\mathfrak{V}$ is still not a maximal atlas. I don't see why I am still guaranteed with the existence of a maximal atlas $\mathfrak{V}$ given some atlas $\mathfrak{U}$.

Comment: The atlas hunter is referring to in that statement is $\mathfrak{M}$, not $\mathfrak{U}$.

Comment: @JamesChung My writing was rather inarticulate. 

Resummarizing: We are given $\mathfrak{U}$ and defining $\mathfrak{M}$ to be the set of all charts compatible with everything in $\mathfrak{U}$. This is obviously maximal if it's an atlas, but it might not be an atlas since we have to check two things in $\mathfrak{M}$ are compatible wtih each other. But this turns out to be true.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.